# CheckBox on Windows Phone Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface

How can I check is there checkbox on my windows phone page? So, I add WrapPanel to my page:

```
            _wp = new WrapPanel
            {
                Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal,
                Height = 80,
            };
            _tb = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = gameText,
                Width = 250
            };
            _wp.Children.Add(_tb);

            _cb = new CheckBox();

            _wp.Children.Add(_cb);

            this.Items.Add(_wp);
```

but I need write handlers to checkbox. I can't do something about this:

> > ```
> >           _cb = new CheckBox { CheckedChanged += my_handler }
> > ```

So, how can I do it?

UPD:

I need make only one CheckBox checked. In handler I want to do all checkboxes but sender to checked=false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
      _cb = new CheckBox ();
_cb.Checked = true;
    _cb. CheckedChanged += my_handler ;
```

You are using `event` like a `property`.

If you want to check if there is any `CheckBox` control on your panel you may try:

```
_wp.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Any();
```

You may use same handler for all of your check boxes.